# How does bgrep work?

Tags: grep, binary

I am studying the command *bgrep* found [here](https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep).
I run `bgrep "fafafa" test_27.6.2015.bin | less -M` on the the binary data called  [test_27.6.2015.bin](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f27f05s5gw733wy/test_27.6.2015.bin?dl=0) but I get

```
test_27.6.2015.bin: 00005ee4
test_27.6.2015.bin: 0000bd3c
```

I would suspect to get matches containing the term *fafafafa*. 
Two matches is the correct amount of matches. 
These hex numbers are probably of some segment containing *fafafafa*.

How does bgrep form its search result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bgrep](https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep)'s search result are formatted this way:

```
printf("%s: %08llx\n", filename, (unsigned long long)(offset + o - len));
```

Hence, it displays the filename, and then the hex offset where the search string started, as illustrated here:

```
$ xxd test_27.6.2015.bin | grep 5ee0
0005ee0: 0c89 0c88 fafa fafa 585e 0000 fe5a 1eda  ........X^...Z..
```